# Weird symbols being inserted when I press Ctrl + V?

Tags: vim, editor

gVim 8.0

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in insert mode (or in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> mode) I got this v-like symbols inserted instead of my current clipboard text.

[image]

Why does it happen? How do I get it back to normal?

Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

[`CTRL-V`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-V) means "Insert next non-digit literally." I.e. if you press <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> twice vim inserts "CTRL-V" into the text and displays it as "^V".

To paste a buffer switch to normal mode and use [<kbd>p</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#p) or <kbd>P</kbd>. You can temporary switch to normal mode with [<kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-O); e.g. <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question (or my issue). The situation I described is not normal, it's not a default state of things. It used to normal when I started to use the program, then something changed but I don't know what exactly. And that's what my question was about. BTW, I've just reinstalled the program and everything got back to normal. Ctrl + V now is working as expected, but I still would like to know what it was. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the omission of this line: `source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim` from `_vimrc` file.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on insert mode use `Ctrl-r +` .
Looking at `:h registers` you will see that `+` means clipboard register and `Ctrl-r` helps us to insert any register on insert mode.

In normal mode you can just type: `"+p`

As being said `Ctrl-v` on insert mode is used to insert special chars. To learn more `:h i_Ctrl-v`

```
                        *i_CTRL-V*
CTRL-V      Insert next non-digit literally.  For special keys, the
        terminal code is inserted.  It's also possible to enter the
        decimal, octal or hexadecimal value of a character
        |i_CTRL-V_digit|.
        The characters typed right after CTRL-V are not considered for
        mapping.
        Note: When CTRL-V is mapped (e.g., to paste text) you can
        often use CTRL-Q instead |i_CTRL-Q|.
```

Comment: "As being said Ctrl-v on insert mode is used to insert special chars" Not by defafult! By default Ctrl-v in Vim pastes text from clipboard (just as standard windows notepad does).